# Mean sphere in hyperbolic 3-space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

What would be the natural equivalent of the notion of a mean sphere at a point of a smooth surface when the surface no longer lives in the Euclidean 3-space but in the hyperbolic 3-space ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a 'mean sphere' at a point of a surface?

Comment: Oops ! I beg your pardon. My English is too weak. The right term is probably "the middle sphere", that is the sphere with center at the midpoint of the focal segment (which connects the two centers of principal curvatures at the point x of the surface which we consider) and with radius the mean of the principal radii of curvatures. This sphere contains the corresponding point x of the surface and is tangent to the surface at that point.

Comment: So the mean curvature of the mean sphere is not necessarily the mean curvature of the surface? Then there might be more than just one possible analogue.